# If your curtains have elaborate box pleats

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of "[box](https://homedecorbliss.com/are-curtains-machine-washable/)" in "If your curtains have elaborate box pleats or embroidered raised stitching, you may consider hand-washing or dry cleaning to protect the intricacy."? I mean, they don't look like boxes to me.

Comment: Just google [**define "box pleats"**](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+%22box+pleats%22&oq=define+%22box+pleats%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.7318j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: I did that before I posted the question and this was what I found: "a pleat consisting of two parallel creases facing opposite directions and forming a raised section in between", but I don't see the explanation of "box" in the definition.

Comment: The text you've just cited *defines* the pleat as a "box"! It means the "cross-section" of the pleat (as if looking down from ceiling to floor) is *rectangular*. Only 3 of the 4 sides physically exist as curtain material (the one opposite the "raised section" is just "notional"). In this context, a "box" is just a three-dimensional rectangle where the curtain material has a couple of right-angle folds to form those 3 sides. Check out [**box girder**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_girder) with all 4 folds (as opposed to an H-section girder, that *doesn't* have a box-shaped cross-section).

Comment: Thank you so much as well for your help! Now I get it 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means "rectangular container". The square folds formed by box pleats look like small rectangular containers.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explanations!

Answer (score 2):

This is what box pleated curtains look like

[image]